# <input type="image"> doesnt seem to be posting

Tags: php, form-submit

I can't figure out why...

This works:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['test']) echo "posted";

?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="test" />
</form>
```

and this doesn't:

```
<?php
    if($_POST['test']) echo "posted";

?>

<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="image" name="test" src="images/button.submit.png" />
</form>
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? because... this is driving me crazy

Comment: Switch to GET and you'll see what's going on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you post via an image the x/y coordinates that were clicked on are sent instead. Check `$_POST['test_x']` and `$_POST['test_y']`

Comment: Correct. To be clear, there is no `$_POST['test']` only `$_POST['test_x']` and `$_POST['test_y']` .

Answer (score 2):

Image inputs only post the x and y co-ordinates of where the click happened, not (necessarily) a value.  If you really want to use an image in this way, you may want to add a hidden field too.