# PHP: SUBMIT Type vs IMAGE Type

Tags: php

I have noticed that when using a SUBMIT type its name attribute gets passed via POST , while an IMAGE type button do not have this data sent, can any one clear this up for me? In both instances the NAME attribute is present at HTML level, but only the SUMBIT type has the NAME sent via POST....is this right?

Comment: sorry, there was some mishap, i have now added all the text to the question

Comment: possible duplicate of [<input type="image"> doesnt seem to be posting.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615483/input-typeimage-doesnt-seem-to-be-posting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit via image, it sends the coordinates of where the image was clicked, so if the image is named `image` you'll have the POST parameters `image_x` and `image_y`

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4:

> **image**
>
> (snip)
>
> When a pointing device is used to click on the image, the form is
>   submitted and the click coordinates
>   passed to the server. The x value is
>   measured in pixels from the left of
>   the image, and the y value in pixels
>   from the top of the image. The
>   submitted data includes name.x=x-value
>   and name.y=y-value where "name" is the
>   value of the name attribute, and
>   x-value and y-value are the x and y
>   coordinate values, respectively.